# jQuery syntax, balancing brackets

Tags: jquery

Is there any syntax problem in above script, balancing brackets? Or another mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winW;
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (winW > 768) {
        $("#refinebox").addClass("in"); 
    }); 
);
```

Comment: Yes, there is. use a tool such as JSLint to help. Proper indentation may help too.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation of your code snippet which may help show the mistake. (Hint: compare the end of your two `if` statements)

Comment: The `});` is premature. That should just be `}`, followed by `});`

Comment: Thanks all. @KevinB I thought JSLint is only for JS not Jquery. ?

Comment: it doesnt recognise $. "'$' was used before it was defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
}); 
);
```

should be

```
} 
});
```

You have braces ending problem..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winW;
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (winW > 768) {
        $("#refinebox").addClass("in"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are best off using indentation at every ( or { to help you see where you have issues.

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
        var winW;
        if (window.innerWidth) {
              winW = window.innerWidth;
        }
        if (winW > 768) {
          $("#refinebox").addClass("in"); 
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a bracket issue. The 2nd if statement should either be closed with just a right curly bracket, or because you only have one line of code inside the if, you don't need curly braces at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var winW;
if (window.innerWidth) {
    winW = window.innerWidth;
}
if (winW > 768) 
$("#refinebox").addClass("in");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing a curly brace to close your function and you have an extra ); at the end. Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winW;
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (winW > 768) {
        $("#refinebox").addClass("in"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got in a bit of a tangle at the end there. Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winW;
    if (window.innerWidth) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
    }
    if (winW > 768) {
        $("#refinebox").addClass("in"); 
    }
});
```